# Running a go program on Android?

Tags: android, go

I have a go library that i want to run on android and use its methods in my android app. I could write the whole android app in go to make it easier to use this dependency. Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: https://github.com/golang/mobile

Comment: The mobile stuff is targeting NDK apps like games, I think, so you lose access to Android's Java UI libraries and such. Gopher bradfitz made an Android app, the Camlistore uploader, that runs a Go program as a child process (and my understanding is that was tricky to do). In other words, progress is happening but you're limited in how you can use Go on Android as of today.

Comment: This is not accurate. You can call into Go from Java on Android. See the example app on https://github.com/golang/mobile/tree/master/example/libhello.

Answer (score 7):

Golang support for mobile development has been steadily improving. Today it is even possible to build some simple all Go apps (depending on which features you need) as well as Go libraries. Please see https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Mobile for more info.

UPDATE: In further improvement, libraries are being created to support even UI on mobile platforms. https://fyne.io provides rather robust set of features for mobile.

Comment: The wiki for Go Mobile has moved to https://go.dev/wiki/Mobile - all information can be found there

Answer (score 6):

Download Termux (Linux Emulator) from google play store and open it.
Next, wait for it to perform an automatic download of its resources. After that operation, the run the following command:
pkg install golang
pkg install git

The got package is required when downloading golang packages.
Eventually, you can test it by running (go) command.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Go library from Java when developing for Android with gobind (see [this](https://github.com/golang/mobile/tree/master/example/libhello) example in the gomobile repository). The biggest issue with this is integration into the build system.

[For Go 1.5 things are getting better](http://godoc.org/golang.org/x/mobile/cmd/gomobile#hdr-Build_a_shared_library_for_android_APK_and_iOS_app), but you'll have to wait for that.